# Monitoring: detect sequence of events

Tags: monitoring, kibana, graphite, influxdb, grafana

i need to monitor my logs and raise alerts when i detect some events. most tools supports querying for thresholds and aggregates but i can't find anything that let you detect event A within 2 minutes time-frame after event B. is it possible with kibana, grafana, graphite? maybe something else?

Answer (score 0):

InfluxData has a tool called [kapacitor](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor) that should allow you to do what you're trying to do.

To achieve what you're trying to do specifically you'll need a [User Defined Function](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v0.13/nodes/u_d_f_node/) that will monitor an event stream and whenever it sees event `B` start a 2 minute timer that watches for event `A` and if event `A` happens pass a `bool` to the next node in the Kapacitor `DAG` that will trigger an [alert](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v0.13/nodes/alert_node/) if that `bool` is true.